# Cannot add Teradata Source in Visual Studio 2013 SSIS

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The `Microsoft Connectors v2.0 for Teradata` has been loaded, but the `Teradata Source` is not available for `DataFlow` in `Vistual Studio 2013`.

I tried to add the Teradata Source through `Tools -> Choose Toolbox Items`, but the tabs of `SSIS Data Flow Items` and `SSIS Control Flow Items` are missing.

How to select the `Teradata Source` for `SSIS` in `Visual Studio 2013` (or `SQL Server Data Tool` for `Visual Studio 2013` in `Microsoft SQL Server 2014`)?